# Can I run an OS command via Oracle 11g via web SQLi?

Tags: oracle, sql-injection

I'm doing some post exploitation work and I've been stuck trying to show a full OS compromise by running a command or uploading a payload.

I've tried using DBMS_SCHEDULER to create an executable job, but the jobs don't seem to be created when I run a query like this.  I'm not real familiar with Oracle 11g (I don't ususally do post exploitation work) and this system seems fairly well patched, but I have DBA access.

Here is an example of what I'm trying via SQLi via the web app:

```
0' OR 1 in ( DBMS_SCHEDULER.CREATE_JOB (job_name=>'test', job_type=>'EXECUTABLE',
job_action=>'c:\windows\syswow64\ping.exe <IP>', enabled=>true) ) AND '1'='1
```

The error I get back is this:

```
OraOLEDB error '80004005'
ORA-00904: "DBMS_SCHEDULER"."CREATE_JOB": invalid identifier
```

I'm not sure if this is a limitation of the query or what. Most of what I've seen around this has the jobs being created within a `BEGIN / END` block.  I'm not sure what that does.

When I looked at the components in dba_registry table, I don't think Java is enabled.

Comment: Should we be helping you trying to hack a system?

Comment: Like I said, I don't normally do post exploitation.  I do testing on a regular basis to identify attack vectors via vulnerabilities.  That said, I understand that a lot of people aren't familiar with proactive security testing and feel discussing openly the methods for attack somehow degrades the security of the internet.  I'm not offended if you don't want to answer.

Comment: You can't "embed" the call to a stored *procedure* into a regular SQL statement (e.g. a `SELECT`). It always needs a statement "of its own". So either by using `execute` or `begin ... end`.

Comment: According to the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25788/d_sched.htm#r4c1-t31) the `job_action` for an `EXECUTABLE` should be 'the name of the external executable, including the full path name, but excluding any command-line arguments'. So I'd guess it doesn't like the `<IP>` part.

Comment: So any thought on concatenation being used where I could end the Select statement then run the stored procedures?  Like it might currently be "Select access, name, userid from users where user ='user field' and pass='pass field'", I can probably append on and make it valid somehow but I'm not familiar with PL/SQL syntax Kung fu.

Comment: I have been able to run SPs , specifically UTL_INADDR inside a select and return the output and I can inject further thru that to run additional commands.  But not reliably the DBMS_SCHEDULER SP.